# regular expression check for closing tag XHTML

Tags: regex, xhtml

The end of my expression is the only part causing me problems, im trying to match `>` not `/>`

something like this: `\s*[^\/]>` however i dont want to match any other characters before the `>`

Here is an example, I want this to match any img tags that are not closed.

```
<img((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)\s*[^\/]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get rid of the `[^\/]` at the end, since you only want to match on the `>`, and no other character:

```
<img((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)\s*>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'(<img.*?(?<=[^/])>)'
```

positive look-behind checks only for preceding characters. As I understand you only need to check if `>` is not preceded by `\`.

As bdukes points out, negative look-behind is another option: `(<img.*?(?<!/)>)`

Comment: This matches the self-closing `img` tags, I think OP wants to match the non-self-closing tags.

Comment: well, one is opposite of the other, no?

Comment: Use `?<!` instead of `?<=` to _not_ match the slash.

Comment: I kinda get what you mean, however i only know basic regexp